# Is it OK to say "most likely want to buy", "secondly likely..." and "thirdly likely..."?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, adverbs, ordinal-numbers

Suppose there are 3 paintings for sale in a gallery, all at the same price, and you have examined them thoroughly. You say:

> I most likely want to buy the first one, and secondly likely want to
>   buy the second one & thirdly likely want to buy the third one.

Is it OK to say something like that? If it is not OK, then how should I express that information?

Comment: 'I'd most like to date the first one; the second one would be my second choice, and the third one my third choice' deals with the grammar and phraseology. The pragmatics is irredeemable.

Comment: and my reply is you would not refer to any by the impersonal `one`; so to me you have concentrated on the relative terms only without addressing the full sentence. It also seems you have assumed the presence of a third party. I'll admit that I have only an inkling of what "The pragmatics is irredeemable." means.

Comment: @ Used_By_Already I'm basically saying that 'you' should not say anything like this in the presence of people who are likely to be offended. This is a question that needs severe recasting. I'll edit.

Comment: There are three bachelors in front of me: the first one is very rich and *most likely* he's a playboy; the second one however is very tall and handsome, *more likely than not*, I'd choose him for myself. The third bachelor out of the three is *the least likely* to get laid.

Comment: You REALLY should wait for other answers before awarding a poster's answer. Raestloz's not bad and the best out of the three, but it's not the best solution.

Comment: I'm astonished by the edits to this question, is it common to rewrite the question to such an extent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't use "secondly likely", instead you use "second most likely".

You may also use "most likely, less likely, and **even** less likely" for that, but I can't imagine a situation where you want to say this in front of the very girls you're categorizing, they might end up changing that sentence to "most likely got slapped by"

EDIT:
The above paragraph was written (typed?) before the question was edited.

There are other ways to express ascending/descending priority such as this case. For example:

- "If I have to choose, I'd take the left one, if that's not available I'd take the middle, if that's not available too I'd take the right one"
- "To me the left painting is the best, middle painting the second best, right painting the third"
- "I prefer left painting over the other paintings, and I prefer the middle painting over the right one"

If you insist on using "most likely", then you can either use descending or ascending style:

- "most likely, second most likely, third most likely" - descending
- "most likely, less likely, even less likely" - descending
- "likely, more likely, most likely" - ascending
- "likely, more likely, even more likely" - ascending

Comment: Answers need to address the fact that 'I most likely want to' should be replaced by 'I'd most like to ...' etc.. See comment under prgSRR's answer.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I personally do not see why you should put *would* before *most*. Far as I see the usage here does not warrant it. This is because "I want to date the first one" is already correct, adding *most likely* does not warrant adding *would*, especially since in the hypothetical situation presented, the girls are already standing before him, not just, say, in photos. He's making  a decision for right that instant instead of a plan for the future

Comment: 'I most likely want to' doesn't make sense. It's almost as bad as saying 'I most likely have two arms'.

Comment: Tricky situation. Could you add an edit and explain how you would approach the "new" and less offensive situation? That way the original answer, which gained two upvotes would still remain intact, but your edit would address the question as it stands now.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I'd still use the same approach, but it's true that there are other ways to express the same concept.

Comment: If OP insists on using 'most likely' with the present tense of 'want' here, he (assuming 'Tom' isn't short for 'Thomasina') is saying he doesn't know his own mind. 'I most likely want to have a coffee at this moment'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth ? isn't that the point of *most likely*?

Comment: You can't use 'most likely' with a situation where the facts are known. *'I most likely feel in pain.' *'I most likely have blonde hair.' *'I most likely am under 150 years old.' *'I most likely like / want the landscape best / most'. In other situations, 'most likely' makes sense: 'You will most likely go to visit Yellowstone when you are in Cody' / 'You most likely need to increase your vitamin C intake'. It means 'The most probable scenario is [that] ...'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I don't understand where all that came from. Nothing in my answer nor in my comments have I implied that using *most likely* for facts is correct, because using *most likely* by itself changes the nature of the sentence and alters its meaning. For example, the sentence "I most likely have blonde hair" means that you do not know the color of your hair but make a guess anyway based on what you currently know.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth if you're referring to the comment where I said "it doesn't warrant adding *would*", I was talking about the sentence structure. *Would* is what you use for past or future, but the context in OP was that he's making a decision for the present instant, thereby not necessitating the use of *would*. "I want a coffee" and "I would want a coffee" have slightly different meaning, and depending on context, the former is already enough

Comment: You'd _really_ have to invent some far-fetched extra context to justify not correcting 'I most likely want to buy the first one' in the edited version. In any register I've met, 'I most likely want to buy ...' means 'The most probable scenario is that I want to buy ...'; surely this makes far less sense than 'The one I most desire to buy ...' here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth you're making too many assumptions. Who's to say you're talking to the cashier? Maybe you're just having a conversation with your friend, maybe it's just something you thought out loud. In any event, what matters here is whether the usage is correct given the context.

Comment: Judging by the closure reason, it appears that the question is not sufficiently clear. In a recent conversation on Meta, it was argued that this constitutes a reason why 'answers' should be / have been delayed. The question **has** to be interpreted – assumptions **have** to be made – when one attempts to answer a question lacking sufficient clarity.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17653/discussion-between-raestloz-and-edwin-ashworth).

Answer (score -1):

`Secondly` likely and `Thirdly` likely would have been appropriate descriptions if you had begun the sentence with `First(ly)` likely. Which is not the case here... :)

So if you have one object/event being described as `Most Likely` then the other objects/events in comparison should be described as `Less Likely` and `Lesser Likely` and `Even Lesser Likely` and so on.

Now that was for diminishing order of likelihood (High-Low). You could also do it the other way around, in increasing order of likelihood (Low-High). That will perhaps sound more straight forward.

Example: I would likely want to date the third girl, more likely want to date the second one, most likely want to date the first one.

Comment: 'I most likely want to date' is ridiculous. 'I would most likely want to date' might work, but the conditional needs a condition: 'I would most likely want to date were I not already married' say.